# Как убрать первые символы из строки?

Tags: python, python-3.x, строки, символы

Да, я знаю, что этот вопрос уже много раз и везде задавался. Но мне НЕ НУЖНО убрать определенные символы. Мне нужно убрать первые.
Допустим есть строка "Helo world!!!1" в переменной mystr, и мне нужно убрать 5 первых символов чтобы получить "world!!!1". Как это сделать?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```py
s = 'Helo world!!!1'

s = s[5:] # world!!!1
```

Comment: Хм. Здесь все начинается с нуля или с единицы?

Comment: @TheNick-Ник с нуля

Comment: спасибо (благодарю)!